# Debugging silverlight app against a remote WCF Service

Tags: wcf, silverlight, cross-domain

I'm having a really strange problem (at least it is strange because it has worked for me in the past) with a Silverlight Application consuming WCF services.

When I debug both Silverlight Application and WCF in localhost it works perfect. When I publish both projects, they work perfect. The problem is when I try to debug the Silverlight Application against published WCF... it throws the typical crossdomain exception.

I promise I've both clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml uploaded into the root path in server.

Looking in fiddler, it doesn't even try to read the clientaccesspolicy file before crashing.

Do you have any idea??? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Put these files inside your service folder

**clientaccesspolicy.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource include-subpaths="true" path="/"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

**crossdomain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I said before, I already have those files in my server (both in the root and in the service path). Anyway your solution has been valid in all my previous issues (for future visitors ;)).

Comment: Are you sure that is inside the service folder? i also have no idea why it is not working. In addition to that also check domain uri whether you have missed something.

Comment: Yes I am :(. If I go to the url I've set for the services, it works... so that's not the problem. I've other projects in the same server and they are working.

Comment: The policy file must be at the root of the web server at http://localhost/clientaccesspolicy.xml